# iOS:Binary operator '|=' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I got an error while performing a bitwise operation on two boolean values.
**Error :"Binary operator '|=' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands"**

```
func checkAvailability(available:Bool) -> Bool{
    var bChanged = false
    bChanged |= available //"Binary operator '|=' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands"
    return bChanged  
}
```

Please any one help me to solve the problem...

Comment: `|=` which operator is this????

Comment: Show us how this operator is defined (it's not in Swift, so you must have defined it somewhere, or maybe it comes from a third-party library).

Comment: Bitwise-OR operation for Bool was removed from Swift, a long time ago.

Comment: @BraneDullet, Bool is not an int in Swift. What behavior do you expect from a **bitwise** or?

Comment: It's not clear what you expect that method to return based on the parameter.

Comment: This is Bitwise OR and assign operator.

Comment: `bChanged = bChanged || available`

Comment: @OOPer That's a no-op.

Comment: I just covert a .net code into swift.In that they uses bitwise operator.

Comment: @OOPer I thing that's a better solution

Comment: No it isn't  It does *nothing*.

Comment: @Droppy, have your tried with actual code?

Comment: @OOPer No, I am able to work it out mentally.

Comment: @Droppy, just try.

Comment: Well given that `bChanged = false` then it's the same as just returning `available`.

Comment: @Droppy, I see. You take that part is sort of actual. But I take that part as just a simplified code which is describing `bChanged` is a `Bool` variable initialized with a certain value. Maybe we should have clarified such points.

Comment: Well it's unclear exactly what the OP wants anyway...

Comment: @Droop , this is my .Net code , I need to convert to swift . 

public bool Changed(string strCCNumber, string strCCName, string strExpMo, string strExpYr)         {             bool bChanged = false;             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CCNumber))             {                 bChanged = (CCNumber != strCCNumber && MaskCCNumber(CCNumber) != strCCNumber);             }             bChanged |= ExpChanged(strExpMo, strExpYr);             return bChanged;         }

where "ExpChanged(strExpMo, strExpYr)" returns a boolean value .

Comment: The equivalent of `bChanged = bChanged || available` would actually be `bChanged ||= available`. But no language that I know of supports that operator. But I agree with @Droppy that it is very unclear what is being asked here.

Comment: @BraneDullet when you add code, edit the question to add it, instead of mentioning it in the comments

Answer (score 5):

You could define it yourself by overloading the operator:

Swift 2:

```
func |= (inout left: Bool, right: Bool) {
   left = left || right
}
```

Swift 3:

```
func |= (left: inout  Bool, right: Bool) {
   left = left || right
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a constructive answer - unlike some of the comments on the OP's question. Just to be consistent I've extended your idea to cover the other two missing operators.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple expansion of Lew's answer to include the other two "missing" operators.

```
// A couple of operators that exist in C# and Java but are missing from Swift.

public func |= (leftSide : inout Bool, rightSide : Bool) {
   leftSide = leftSide || rightSide
}

public func &= (leftSide : inout Bool, rightSide : Bool) {
   leftSide = leftSide && rightSide
}

public func ^= (leftSide : inout Bool, rightSide : Bool) {
   leftSide = leftSide != rightSide
}
```